# Defining types in SML?

Tags: string, types, pattern-matching, sml, smlnj

If I want to check if a string starts with a letter and the rest of the characters can either be a letter or number, how would I define a datatype that is defined by those conditions? Or would pattern matching be the better route and if so, how would I check that?

Comment: You really wouldn't define a *datatype* to define that. Instead, write a function of type `string -> bool` that verifies the condition. Hint: it *starts with a letter* `andalso` *the rest of the string has a certain property*. Look at some of the SML standard library functions on strings and characters. You could explode the string to a list of characters and verify that the head of the list satisfies one property and the tail of the list another.

Comment: So would my function be along the lines of this? `fun isName(s : string): bool =
    val exp = String.explode(s)
 if ((isAlpha(hd exp)) andalso map(isAlphaNum, tl exp) then true
  else false`

Comment: Or should it be more along the lines of this? `fun isName(s : string): bool =
   val exp = String.explode(s)
 if isAlpha(hd exp) then
 let
     fun chk (x::xs) = if isAlphaNum x then chk(xs)
     else false 
       | chk ([]) = true
 in
     chk(tl(exp))
 end
 else false`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care that using `String.explode` is a bit inefficient, then you can just define this predicate:

```
fun isName s = List.all Char.isAlpha (String.explode s)
```

Otherwise, you'd implement it via recursion over (the length of) the string itself.